# Checking if a string is a valid date using moment

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I am using `momentjs` to check if a string is a valid date. 
momentjs has the following format for validation:

```
moment(date,  formats, true).isValid()
```

In my case, I do not want to give formats as I only want to check if the string is valid date or not, I do not care about the format. 
I tried the following:

```
moment("date string").isValid()
```

Although, this gives the correct response, I also get error in console. Is there any way to only check if date without formats?

```
Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across
all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Arguments:
[0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: Sat Sep 08 2050 01:27:14 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]
Error
    at Function.createFromInputFallback (F:\myproj\backend\node_modules\moment\moment.js:320:98)
    at configFromString (F:\myproj\backend\node_modules\moment\moment.js:2385:15)
    at configFromInput (F:\myproj\backend\node_modules\moment\moment.js:2611:13)
    at prepareConfig (F:\myproj\backend\node_modules\moment\moment.js:2594:13)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript has only one official date/time format, the one [defined in the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format) based on ISO-8601, for example `"2019-09-07T08:16:55.216Z"`. What Moment is telling you is that you didn't provide the format to use to parse the date and the date didn't fit JavaScript's format, so Moment had to fall back to using `new Date` and hoping it did the right thing. As the message says, that's unreliable across browsers, because they can all implement their own *"...implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats..."* ([source](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date.parse)). That means that a given string that Chrome parses may not be parsed on Safari, or worse, may be parsed **differently** (for instance, using local time vs. UTC).

So the upshot is: Unless the date is in JavaScript's format, to get reliable results you **have** to tell Moment what format to use to parse it.

Comment: Oh thanks, but in my case, I am doing the validation at nodejs and date comes as part of API request body, it can be any string and I want to validate if the string passed is a valid date. So, I guess I will have to go with some other module instead of moment. or will have to add all possible date formats in the array.

Comment: @Noober - *"... it can be any string..."* Then it's **impossible** for you to reliably parse it. I don't mean it's impossible for Moment or JavaScript, I mean it's impossible, full stop. What date/time does `"05-03-2019 02:00"` represent? In the U.S., you'd probably say 2 a.m. on May 3rd 2019. Basically anywhere else (the UK, Europe, ...), you'd say 2 a.m. March 5th 2019. See the problem? But wait, it gets worse: What time zone is that in? V8 will treat it as local time, but another engine could treat it as UTC -- or refuse to parse it at all (JavaScriptCore in Safari). *(cont'd)*

Comment: *(continuing)* Whatever API you're dealing with should define the date/time format and only accept date/time strings in that format, and none other. Now, if you want to leave yourself open to completely misinterpreting the dates you get, you can avoid the error from Moment by doing `moment(new Date(theString))`. But I **strongly** encourage you not to do that. Specify a format and only parse that format. :-)

Comment: (Not so fun fact: Even in the UK, `new Date("05/03/2019")` parses as May 3rd, not March 5th. Why? Because although it wasn't specified, early versions of the JavaScript engine in Netscape Navigator did that, because they were U.S.-centric. To avoid breaking poorly-written JavaScript code, every JavaScript engine that came after had to do the same thing. This has led to hundreds of thousands of errors in the rest of the world because coders assumed `new Date` would do the right thing for the locale.)